# Invite user to install an iOS App using Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an iOS social app, which used Facebook to login. Now I have access to the friends list. Is there a way to send a request to a Facebook friend (who is currently not using app) to install my App. What I mean to say how can you advertise an app using Facebook circle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FBWebDialogs, there's a presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession method which does what you need.

You can also see this tutorial - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/

Comment: I tried it already, it only allow me to send messages to the Friends who are already using my app... Infect I want to invite new people

Comment: That's not true, you can use the requests dialog to send requests to any friend. Please post code on how you're using it.

Comment: "Infect" is the word... *scnr*